# Installing MS QDK to run Q# with python on Ubuntu 18 -- "dotnet iqsharp install" step fails

Tags: python, ubuntu, q#

Using the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/install-guide/pyinstall

I get following:

**dotnet iqsharp install**

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
**The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.0.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.**

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.18.04-x64

It seems you cannot get AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 anymore but I have 3.0.3 installed - See below here for my setup .....

**dotnet --info**

.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.102
 Commit:    573d158fea

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.2
  Commit:  916b5cba26

.NET Core SDKs installed:

3.0.103 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

3.1.102 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

PATH=/home/dramsay/Qcomp-env/bin:/home/dramsay/bin:/home/dramsay/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dramsay/.dotnet/tools:/snap/dotnet-sdk/63/host/fxr/3.1.2:/snap/dotnet-sdk/63/sdk:/snap/dotnet-sdk/63/host/fxr/3.1.2:/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App:/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Answer (score 2):

This is an actual dependency issue with the tool itself.

I've copied your question and repro steps to an issue on the github here:
https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues/102

Comment: Thanks Stefan - that is good news and I will try more options as per the Github comments